# Error when trying to start Apache after installing Passenger for puppet

Tags: apache2, puppet, puppetmaster

I am having an issue that I am not able to start Apache after installing passenger and configuring the puppetmaster file in /etc/apache2/sites-available/.

I am getting the following error when I try to start Apache:

```
root@puppet-master:/etc/apache2/sites-available# service apache2 start
 * Starting web server apache2
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:8140
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
```

I don't know if the problem is related to the puppetmaster file or the apache2.conf or ports.conf files.

**ports.conf**:

```
root@puppet-master:/etc/apache2/sites-available# cat ../ports.conf
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
# This is also true if you have upgraded from before 2.2.9-3 (i.e. from
# Debian etch). See /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/NEWS.Debian.gz and
# README.Debian.gz

NameVirtualHost *:8140
Listen 8140

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

**apache2.conf**:

```
root@puppet-master:/etc/apache2/sites-available# cat ../apache2.conf
#
# Based upon the NCSA server configuration files originally by Rob McCool.
#
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ for detailed information about
# the directives.
#
# Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
# what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
# consult the online docs. You have been warned.
#
# The configuration directives are grouped into three basic sections:
#  1. Directives that control the operation of the Apache server process as a
#     whole (the 'global environment').
#  2. Directives that define the parameters of the 'main' or 'default' server,
#     which responds to requests that aren't handled by a virtual host.
#     These directives also provide default values for the settings
#     of all virtual hosts.
#  3. Settings for virtual hosts, which allow Web requests to be sent to
#     different IP addresses or hostnames and have them handled by the
#     same Apache server process.
#
# Configuration and logfile names: If the filenames you specify for many
# of the server's control files begin with "/" (or "drive:/" for Win32), the
# server will use that explicit path.  If the filenames do *not* begin
# with "/", the value of ServerRoot is prepended -- so "foo.log"
# with ServerRoot set to "/etc/apache2" will be interpreted by the
# server as "/etc/apache2/foo.log".
#

### Section 1: Global Environment
#
# The directives in this section affect the overall operation of Apache,
# such as the number of concurrent requests it can handle or where it
# can find its configuration files.
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the LockFile documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#lockfile>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
LockFile ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}/accept.lock

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5

##
## Server-Pool Size Regulation (MPM specific)
##

# prefork MPM
# StartServers: number of server processes to start
# MinSpareServers: minimum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxSpareServers: maximum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxClients: maximum number of server processes allowed to start
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# worker MPM
# StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# ThreadLimit: ThreadsPerChild can be changed to this maximum value during a
#              graceful restart. ThreadLimit can only be changed by stopping
#              and starting Apache.
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxClients: maximum number of simultaneous client connections
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# event MPM
# StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
# MinSpareThreads: minimum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of worker threads which are kept spare
# ThreadsPerChild: constant number of worker threads in each server process
# MaxClients: maximum number of simultaneous client connections
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#

AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Files>

#
# DefaultType is the default MIME type the server will use for a document
# if it cannot otherwise determine one, such as from filename extensions.
# If your server contains mostly text or HTML documents, "text/plain" is
# a good value.  If most of your content is binary, such as applications
# or images, you may want to use "application/octet-stream" instead to
# keep browsers from trying to display binary files as though they are
# text.
#
# It is also possible to omit any default MIME type and let the
# client's browser guess an appropriate action instead. Typically the
# browser will decide based on the file's extension then. In cases
# where no good assumption can be made, letting the default MIME type
# unset is suggested  instead of forcing the browser to accept
# incorrect  metadata.
#
DefaultType None


#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
Include mods-enabled/*.load
Include mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include all the user configurations:
Include httpd.conf

# Include ports listing
Include ports.conf

#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive (see below).
# If you are behind a reverse proxy, you might want to change %h into %{X-Forwarded-For}i
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
Include conf.d/

# Include the virtual host configurations:
Include sites-enabled/
```

**puppetmaster**:

```
root@puppet-master:/etc/apache2/sites-available# cat puppetmaster
# Example puppetmaster.conf configuration file for Pluralsight's Puppet Fundamentals for System Administrators course


   LoadModule passenger_module /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.56/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
     PassengerRoot /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.56
     PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.8
   </IfModule>

PassengerHighPerformance on
PassengerMaxPoolSize 12
PassengerPoolIdleTime 1500
PassengerMaxRequests 1000
PassengerStatThrottleRate 120

Listen 8140

<VirtualHost *:8140>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLProtocol             ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3
        SSLCipherSuite          EDH+CAMELLIA:EDH+aRSA:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH:+CAMELLIA256:+AES256:+CAMELLIA128:+AES128:+SSLv3:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!DSS:!RC4:!SEED:!IDEA:!ECDSA:kEDH:$

        SSLHonorCipherOrder     on

        SSLCertificateFile      /var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/puppet-master.localdomain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   /var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/puppet-master.localdomain.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/ca_crt.pem
        SSLCACertificateFile    /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/ca_crt.pem
        SSLCARevocationFile     /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/ca_crl.pem
        SSLVerifyClient optional
        SSLVerifyDepth  1
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData

        RequestHeader unset X-Forwarded-For

        RequestHeader set X-SSL-Subject %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN}e
        RequestHeader set X-Client-DN %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN}e
        RequestHeader set X-Client-Verify %{SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY}e

        DocumentRoot /usr/share/puppet/rack/puppetmasterd/public/
        RackBaseURI /
        <Directory /usr/share/puppet/rack/puppetmasterd/>
                Options None
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        PassengerAppRoot /usr/share/puppet/rack/puppetmasterd
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/puppet-server.example.com_ssl_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/puppet-server.example.com_ssl_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Puppet master is turned off now so nothing is using the 8140 port:

```
root@puppet-master:/etc/apache2/sites-available# sudo netstat -tnlp | grep 8140
root@puppet-master:/etc/apache2/sites-available#
```

Also Apache is turned off so neither start or restart works with it.

```
root@puppet-master:/etc/apache2/sites-available# sudo service apache2 start
 * Starting web server apache2
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:8140
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
root@puppet-master:/etc/apache2/sites-available# sudo service apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:8140
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
```

Is it possible that someone helps me with that?

Thanks..

Comment: Edit your post to include the output of `sudo netstat -tnlp | grep 8140`, please. Also: should you be starting apache2 or **re**starting it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the ServerName directive in apache2's main config file. You also already have an app running on port 8140, which is probably just a stale run of the same program. You can find what program, and port that is already bound to that port with 'ss -nap | grep 8140', or 'sudo netstat -nap | grap 8140'

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2268992